# How to resize multiple divs at the same time smoothly when hover over each one using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, width

What I want to do is

increase the **width of the div** that gets **hovered over** and equally decrease the width of the other 3 divs.

So if **"div1"** get hovered over,
then **"div1"** width needs to be **"40%"**

and

the **other 3 divs** widths would go to **"20%"** which would equal **100%**

This works with the code I have, but its not smooth and when I hover fast over multiple divs everything goes haywire. It's very buggy

What am I doing wrong?

**Link of what I'm trying to do**: https://constructlar.atakansaracoglu.com/

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="div1">
   </div><div class="div2">
   </div><div class="div3">
   </div><div class="div4">
   </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.container div {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 25%;
}
```

My Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.container div').hover(function(){
     let $this = $(this);
     $this.siblings().animate({
       'width' : '19%'
     },200);
     $this.delay(200).animate({
       'width' :'40%'
     },300);
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you should quit using JS. CSS flexbox will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS and `transition` property instead of `jQuery` makes the page smoother.

```css
.container div {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 25%;
   height: 100px;
   transition: width 0.4s;
}

.container:hover div {
    width: 20%;
}

.container div:hover {
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="div1" style="background:red">
   </div><div class="div2" style="background:cyan">
   </div><div class="div3" style="background:yellow">
   </div><div class="div4" style="background:green">
   </div>
</div>
```